# Union with bitfield gives unexpected value to bitfield members

Tags: c++, unions, bit-fields

I have the following construct meant to take a 48bit value that contains four 12bit values and extract them.

```
struct foo {
    union {
        unsigned __int64 data;
        struct {
            unsigned int a      : 12;
            unsigned int b      : 12;
            unsigned int c      : 12;
            unsigned int d      : 12;
            unsigned int unused : 16;
        };
    };
} foo;
```

The data in question is then assigned using

```
foo.data = (unsigned __int64)Value;
```

**Value** here is initially a double used to store the data.

My assumptions when making a bit field are

- The data holding variable should be big enough to hold the entire
  data and unsigned. So a **unsigned __int64** to hold 48 bits.
- Each bitfield member should be of a type big enough to hold the
  number of bits that is assigned to it and be unsigned.
- It's a good idea to keep all bitfield members the same type if
  possible. (to avoid alignment issues?)
- The **unused** member is not actually needed.

Are these correct?

Testing with

```
Value = 206225551364
```

we get a **Value** that should contain the bits

```
0000 0011 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0100‬
```

This should result in

```
a: 0000 0000 0100‬ = 4
b: 0000 0000 0011 = 3
c: 0000 0000 0100 = 4
d: 0000 0000 0011 = 3
```

But running this the actual returned values are

```
a: 4
b: 3
c: 48
d: 0
```

Although the values should fit within the **unsigned int's** switching around the types used sometimes changed the values. So it felt like it had something to do with how the data was interpreted when added to the bitfield.

By adding **#pragma pack(1)**, which I understand has something to do with alignment but haven't come across very often, I all of a sudden get the expected values.

```
struct foo {
    union {
        unsigned __int64 data;
#pragma pack(1)
        struct {
            unsigned int a      : 12;
            unsigned int b      : 12;
            unsigned int c      : 12;
            unsigned int d      : 12;
            unsigned int unused : 16;
        };
    };
} foo;

a: 4
b: 3
c: 4
d: 3
```

But I don't feel comfortable just accepting this. I want to understand it and thus ensure it actually works and isn't just appearing to work while the values don't take up more than 4 bits for instance.

So,

- why am I seeing the issue to begin with?
- What does the **#pragma pack** statement do that fixes the issue?
- Can one deduce when this will become a problem and not? Is it because
  the values are 12 bits and not 8 bits or 16 bits for instance?

Comment: I feel a bit stupid to mention it but type punning with `union` is prohibited in C++ (while it's still allowed in C with the respective constraints).

Comment: @Scheff: No, this is good information. I got this idea from the wonderful world of Internet and as we know, that doesn't always mean that it is good or accurate.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What happens if you remove the `#pragma pack` and insert an `assert(sizeof (foo) == sizeof(__int64));`? (In my paranoidity, I would leave the latter in code even if the former made it working for now.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: Without the pragma directive the assertion fails. With the directive it doesn't.

Comment: That difference is the padding to get boundary alignment.

Comment: TL;DR do not use unions or bit fields for this task. Use bit masks. This method is well-defined and portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why am I seeing the issue to begin with?

Firstly, accessing inactive member of union has undefined behaviour. But let us assume that your system allows it.

`unsigned` is probably 32 bits. a and b fit into the first `unsigned` taking a total of 24 bits. There is only 8 bits left of this `unsigned`. 12 bit c does not fit into this 8 bit slot. So, it instead starts a new `unsigned` leaving 8 bits of padding.

This is one possible outcome. Bit field layout is implementation defined. On another system you might see the outcome that you expected. Or output that is different from what you expect and different from what you observed here.

> What does the #pragma pack statement do that fixes the issue?

It probably changes the layout rules to allow "straddling" of the bitfield across multiple underlying objects. This probably makes accessing it *a bit* slower.

> Can one deduce when this will become a problem and not?

If you don't try to straddle the underlying objects, then there won't be a difference in whether the layout supports that. In this case, you could simply use a 64 bit underlying object.

This is not the only way the layout of bitfields might differ from what you expect though. Bitfields could be most significant first or last for example. The number of bits in `unsigned` itself is implementation defined.

In general, layout of bitsets is not something that should be relied upon.

> How would, what I want to achieve best be done then?

To avoid UB, instead of punning through union, you can create the other object, and copy the bytes from one over the other. But first, you must make sure the object have the same size. The copying can be done with `std::memcpy` or `std::bit_cast`.

To avoid issues with straddling, use sets of bitfields that fill each underlying object completely. In this case by using a 64 bit underlying object.

To get reliable layout, **don't use bitfields in the first place**. [bartop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3414900/bartop) shows how to do this with shifts and masks. (although, the layout still relies on endianness)

Comment: My first thought was that this was an "endian" issue, rather than packing... but it could easily be both.  So... "what he said".  And if you want cross platform compatibility you have to compensate for different machines using different "endianness"... for packets or binary save files for example.  Fun times.  There are any number of macros and functions out there to solve the problem, you're hardly the first person to have it (and in fact: you don't have this problem (yet)).

Comment: I understand now that bitfields, and especially with unions, isn't as straight forward as I thought. But am I to understand that if the initial data fits in an unsigned __int64 and each bitfield member is an unsigned __int64 the issue I came across would not be a problem? Or can it still be an issue depending on the compiler?

Comment: @inquam You would not have problems with straddling multiple objects. But does it matter to you whether the fields are ordered abcdp, or pdcba? If it matters, then you may potentially have a problem.

Comment: It matters so much as to me having to be sure it can't change on the given platform. This is code that will only be compiled on a single OS and for a given architecture. So as long as that doesn't change it would be "ok". But I understand endian can be an issue if the code is to be protable.

Comment: @inquam You would also have to stick to a single compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short - casting data via `union` is undefined behaviour, regardless of what you are doing. So it works and does not work just by accident. Only thing you are allowed to do with `union` is read the member you wrote to last time. You do anything other and your program is invalid.

EDIT:

And even if this was allowed, without `#pragma pack` you depend on data alignment within the struct. Which is probably is 32 or 64 bits. So in this case your struct really looks like this in memory:

```
struct {
    unsigned int a      : 12;
    unsigned int a_align: 20;
    unsigned int b      : 12;
    unsigned int b_align: 20;
    unsigned int c      : 12;
    unsigned int c_align: 20;
    unsigned int d      : 12;
    unsigned int d_align: 20;
    unsigned int unused : 16;
    unsigned int unused_align: 16;

};
```

If you want to extract some data from the struct you should probably use masking and bitshifts like this:

```
unsigned mask12 = 0xFFF;//1 on first 12 least significant bits
unsigned a = data & mask12;
unsigned b = (data >> 12) & mask12;
unsigned c = (data >> 24) & mask12;
unsigned d = (data >> 36) & mask12;
```

Comment: Great to know... hehe. I got this idea from the wonderful world of Internet and as we know, that doesn't always mean that it is good or accurate. How would, what I want to achieve best be done then?

Comment: Using for example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: @inquam added how to do it to the answer